# Living in India with a Kenyan passport and OCI card, just got my Portuguese passport. Immigration to the UK without problems

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, kenyan-citizens, portuguese-citizens

Kenyan passport holder living in India with an OCI card for the last 20 years, just got my Portuguese passport and living for the UK soon and wanted some information about the immigration part, whilst leaving India, I need to show my Kenyan passport and OCI card and when I reach the UK do I show my Portuguese passport only? Once in the UK I plan to apply for dual nationality, Kenyan and Portuguese, will this create any problems for me?

Comment: Why do you say you plan to apply for dual nationality? If you have the passports, then you have already got those nationalities!

Answer (score 0):

A Portuguese citizen generally cannot be refused entry to the UK, and can live there for the rest of their lives without any permission (which will change after Brexit, but you'll be treated under the current rules).

So yes, just show your Portuguese passport at UK immigration.

Also, you say you're applying for dual nationality. If you have both a Kenyan and Portuguese passport, then you're already a dual national.

Comment: highly appreciated. follow on question, once I leave India at the airport I show my Kenyan Passport and OCI card and get them stamped to indicate exit from the country and once I reach the UK airport ( Heathrow ) won't they inquire and cause problems with me having the Kenyan passport and OCI card with the exit stamp and not the Portuguese passport? And that is without having the dual citizenship being officially recognized by the Kenyan High Commission, that I will do once in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelFernandes "won't they inquire and cause problems with me having the Kenyan passport and OCI card with the exit stamp and not the Portuguese passport?" No, they don't have the ***right*** to cause problems for that reason. The ***only*** valid reason to uphold you is if they think your Portuguese passport is counterfeit or forged, i.e. if they suspect you're not really an EU citizen. But dual nationals do exist, lots of them, which I'm 100% sure these people know.

Comment: you are really helpful, you have no idea how many people I have made inquiries with regarding the above, so just to be clear I can leave India using my Kenyan Passport which has the OCI stamp and enter the UK using my Portuguese passport all the while not having applied for the dual nationality in the Kenyan High Commision, which is what I will do once I am in the UK, as we are given a time period of 90 days to declare dual nationality with regards to Kenyan passport holders.

Comment: @Coke the doubly emphasized "only" in your comment overlooks the other grounds under the freedom of movement directive: public health, public safety, and public policy.

Comment: @phoog All of which are highly unlikely to apply to OP.

Comment: @MichaelFernandes Correct. I have heard that Indian immigration check boarding passes and proof that you can enter the destination. If they ask for a UK visa, Show your Portuguese passport

Comment: @MichaelFernandes For allowed cases of multiple nationality, the general principles are: (1) to the authorities of a country of which you are a citizen, always show that country's passport (or other document), and (2) for any other country, pick one nationality and stick with it; in particular, use the same passport to leave that you used when you entered.

Comment: very much appreciated, very helpful. If I have any followup questions may I address them to you at a later date?

Comment: @MichaelFernandes Absolutely, but you should post it as a new question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Coke of course they are highly unlikely to apply to the OP, but overly simplified information on the internet easily becomes misinformation when taken out of context.

Comment: @phoog Guess you're right. Would edit the comment if not for the time limit

Comment: @Coke Similar to phoog's comment the "and can live there for the rest of their lives without any permission (which will change after Brexit, but you'll be treated under the current rules)" clause has some complications in both parts (it presumably won't apply to the OP, but there are circumstance in which EU citizens are being deported, and unless I've missed big new, the status of EU citizens post Brexit hasn't been finalised).

Comment: @origimbo Freedom of movement will end, that much is clear.